# whenever I run my c++ programm, my program has stopped working

Tags: c++

I am very new in data structures and algorithm. I get stuck in my program. I could not find the reason why it happens. whenever I run, a display pop-up and show `file.exe` has stopped working. If you guys know the problem, please help me. And, if I have mistaken somewhere in writing, please ignore it. Because, English is not my primary language.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class List{
private:
    int m_count;
    int *m_items;
public:
    int Get(int index);
    void Insert(int index, int val);
    int Search(int val);
    void Remove(int index);
};

int List::Get(int index){
    if(index < 0 || index > m_count){
        return -1;
    }
    return m_items[index];
}

void List::Insert(int index, int val){
    if(index < 0 || index > m_count){
        return;
    }
    int *OldArray = m_items;
    m_count++;
    m_items = new int[m_count];
    for(int i=0, j=0; i<m_count; i++){  
        if(index == i){
            m_items[i] = val;
        }else{
            m_items[i] = OldArray[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    delete [] OldArray;
}

int List::Search(int val){
    for(int i=0; i<m_count; ++i){
        if(m_items[i] == val){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

void List::Remove(int index){
    if(index < 0 || index > m_count){
        return;
    }
    int *OldArray = m_items;
    m_count--;
    m_items = new int[m_count];
    for(int i=0, j=0; i<m_count; ++i,++j){
        if(index == j){
            j++;
        }
        m_items[i] = m_items[j];
    }
    delete [] OldArray;
}

int main(){
List list;
list.Insert(0, 1);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should run this through your debugger.  It will tell you the exact line where the crash happened and will let you see the values of all variables at that point in time.

Comment: One issue: `Get` has Undefined Behavior if `index == m_count`.

Comment: You never initialize the data-members of the `List` class. They will have *indeterminate* values, and using such indeterminate values in any way leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Change `m_items` to use `std::vector<int>` and let `std::vector` manage memory for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member `m_items` is not initialized.

Calling `list.Insert(0, 1);` will make it execute `delete [] OldArray;` with an uninitialized value.

Add a constructor to initialize the members like:

```
List() : m_count(0), m_items(nullptr) {}
```

Also you should follow [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). In other words, you should also define a copy constructor, an assignment operator, and a destructor to copy the contents of the array instead of simply copying the pointer and to avoid troubles when the objects are copied.